# FragmentStatePagerAdapter doesn't call its fragments

Tags: android, fragment, pager

I have `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` in a fragment with pager. Inside pager I have two fragments to switch between them. What is happening is that when I first come to fragment everything is done correctly, but when I go back and return there again then on the base fragment is called normally `onCreate`, `onCreateView` and so on, but on fragments in pager is not called anything, `getItem` on adapter is not called and pager view is blank. On all fragments I have `setRetainInstance(true)` which is needed due to a rotation behaviour handling.
Can you help me guys what to do with that?